# Is it possible to execute a condition differently in a multiple condition while loop without creating an entire new while loop?

Tags: ruby

I don't really know how to word this short enough for me to google it.

But is it possible to execute a certain condition in a multiple condition `while` loop *differently*, without creating a whole entire `while` loop.

For example, Is it possible to do something like this

```
while num == "" || num == "0"
   #ENTER CODE
```

Instead of doing this

```
while num == ""
   print "YOU MUST ENTER A NUMBER!"
   num = gets.chomp
end

while num == "0"
   print "ZERO IS NOT A VALID NUMBER!"
   num = gets.chomp
end
```

I want to know is it possible to do this, but make it look more visually appealing and concise.

Comment: Try `while num == "" || "0"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick, one loop and use conditionals for which error message to print.

```
while num == "" || num == "0"
  print "YOU MUST ENTER A NUMBER!" if num == ""
  print "ZERO IS NOT A VALID NUMBER!" if num == "0"
  num = gets.chomp
end
```

Comment: Short and Pretty! This is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could write something like this:

```
while num.to_i.zero?
  case number
  when ''
    print 'YOU MUST ENTER A NUMBER!'
  when '0' 
    print 'ZERO IS NOT A VALID NUMBER!'
  end

  num = gets.chomp
end
```

This works, because `to_i` returns `0` for both the string `"0"` and `nil`.

Furthermore I would suggest to change the error message to simplify the code even more:

```
while num.to_i.zero?
  print 'Please enter a number greater then zero'
  num = gets.chomp
end
```

Comment: I didn't think to use case and when statements. I'll come add this to my repertoire of knowledge. Thanks!